# Add time delay in each rows

Tags: python

For example,

I have 100 rows code.

I want to add 1s delay in each line code.

One way is to add `time.sleep(1)` before each line, which is too stupid.

Any smart method?

Thanks all

Comment: why do you think that method is stupid? Also, what is the delay even for?

Comment: I've done this before when debugging using sed (`sed 's/$/\ntime\.sleep\(1\)/g' file.py > file_test.py`), but I think you need to add more details if you are looking for a specific solution

Comment: That is the best and most inefficient way. It's also the smartest way

Answer (score 1):

You can use settrace.
Example:

```
import sys
import time
import datetime

def waitTrace(frame, event, arg):
    if event == "line":
        print("Current time: {}, sleeping for 2 secs".format(datetime.datetime.now().time()))
        time.sleep(2)
    return waitTrace

def f():
    print('test')
    print('test1')
    print('test2')

sys.settrace(waitTrace)
f()
```

output:

```
Current time: 10:46:58.147409, sleeping for 2 secs
test
Current time: 10:47:00.148788, sleeping for 2 secs
test1
Current time: 10:47:02.150878, sleeping for 2 secs
test2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This code seems to hang in an infinite loop

Comment: @JohnColeman it is working perfectly for me

Comment: When I save it in a module and try to run that module in either Spyder or IDLE it just hangs and I have to kill the process. The code is apparently sensitive to *how* it is being run.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your IDE or text editor to add in time.sleep() after every new line if whitespace, just format your codeblocks such that they don't have any new lines unless you want to wait before it. There are other ways to do it too, you just need to add that method to every new line.

For example instead of:

```
for x in y:

    do_something()
```

Write it as:

```
for x in y:
    do_something():
```

Other than that tough luck, this is gonna be quite tedious unless your code is formatted exactly right.